# sum and product rules of probability in Bishop's book

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, beta-distribution

There is already an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/sum-and-product-rules-of-probability) for that but it skips some mathematics, where I am getting stuck.

I am reading Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning.

In Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (page 73, chapter 2.1.) there is a formula:

$$p(x=1|\mathcal{D})=\int_0^1 p(x=1|\mu)p(\mu|\mathcal{D})\text{d}\mu $$

The answer in another thread by applying the product rule states:

$$\int_0^1 p(x=1|\mu)p(\mu|\mathcal D)\mathrm d \mu = \int_0^1 p(x=1,\mu|\mathcal D) \mathrm d \mu $$

And that is exactly where I get stuck.

My calculations:

$$p(x=1|\mu)p(\mu|\mathcal D) = \frac{p(\mu|x=1) p(x=1) p(\mathcal D|\mu) p(\mu)}{p(\mu) p(\mathcal D)} = \frac{p(x=1, \mu)p(\mu,\mathcal D)}{p(\mu) p(\mathcal D)}$$

And I do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: I get your need to derive this, but it can also be seen just verbalizing what the expression is saying: the probability of success on the next trial depends on the parameter $\mu$, which is, tautologically, $p$ in a Bernoulli experiment. But we don't know $p$, although we know the data, and we know that the data already observed changes the probability of $p$ being one value or another. So, there...

Comment: good, but I need a derivation and the rules for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a particular result derived from the laws of probabilities 1.31 and 1.32 given in page 19, namely,

$$
p(x) = \int p(x,y)dy
$$
$$
p(x,y) = p(y|x)p(x)
$$

In your expression, $D$ is fixed, and it may help you to first ignore it. It represents the data sample, but it does not play any role in that particular step.

Just to make it explicit after your question:
$$
p(x=1|D) = \int_{0}^{1}p(x=1, \mu|D)d\mu 
$$
because of the first law, and now applying the second,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}p(x=1, \mu|D)d\mu = \int_{0}^{1}p(x=1| \mu)p(\mu|D)d\mu
$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: The answer seems a bit short for me. You want to tell that there is no point in "my calculations" because of $$\int_0^1 p(x=1|\mu)p(\mu|\mathcal{D})\text{d}\mu  = p(\mu)\int_0^1 p(\mu|\mathcal{D})\text{d}\mu$$ ? If yes, how do I get from $$p(x=1|\mathcal{D})$$ to $$\int_0^1 p(x=1|\mu)p(\mu|\mathcal{D})\text{d}\mu $$

Comment: @Tonja refer to the first two lines of this answer. Step 1: write the marginal you have as a joint where the unwanted thing is being integrated out. Step 2: write the joint as a product. Check step 2 by plugging in the definition of a conditional density, and watch how terms cancel.

Comment: Lets say $$(x=1|D) = z$$. From the first law : $$p(z) = \int_{0}^{1}p(z,\mu)d\mu  = \int_{0}^{1}p(x=1|D,\mu)d\mu $$ How do we get from there to  $$  \int_{0}^{1}p(x=1,\mu|D)d\mu$$ ?

Comment: Because you assume that the next sample does not depend on the previous data (iid), and the probability of getting x=1 is given by the variable $\mu$. The term p(\mu|D) is the one where you update your prior beliefs according to the observed data. p(x=1|\mu) are the predictions of your updated model.