# Predictive distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, beta-distribution

Reading Bishop's book, I was trying to prove eq 2.19. I have seen [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/sum-and-product-rules-of-probability) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283510/sum-and-product-rules-of-probability-in-bishops-book?noredirect=1&lq=1) and I understand how

$$p(x=1|D)=\int_0^1p(x=1|μ)p(μ|D)dμ$$

My question is in the second part. How does

$$\int_0^1p(x=1|μ)p(μ|D)dμ=\int_0^1\mu p(μ|D)dμ$$

In other words, how does $p(x=1|\mu)$ equal to $\mu$.

Comment: What is Bishop's book?

Comment: Bishop - Pattern Recognition And Machine Learning - Springer 2006

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the book in front of me but presumably $x$ is a binomial random variable with mean $\mu$. This translates to $P(x=1)=\mu$ and $P(x=0)=1-\mu$, where $\mu$ is the probability of heads (Work out $E[x]$ to confirm this).